# .htaccess HTTPS for all except specific files

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with a redirect in my .htaccess-File.
Basically I want to send all requests to the HTTPS, which works perectly:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.de/$1 [R,L]
```

Now I need the exception for a few images:
For example, when its /fileadmin/rss.png it has to be http://www.domain.de/fileadmin/rss.png and not the HTTPS version. Whatever I've tried so far, nothing worked. For example; I've added a `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443` at the front and set the RewriteRule for the specific image. But still, the redirect was set to HTTPS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fileadmin/rss\.png$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.de/$1 [R,L]
```

Be sure you're familiar with the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Ahhh! I've tried to make seperate redirects for those and probably the first one had a higher priority than the ones below. Thank you so much! :)